# Effectirve rows removal in RocksDB

Tags: c++, database, key-value, rocksdb

I need to loop over all key-values in RocksDB in order to fill my POD collection. I don't need to store key-values after retrieval. What should I use - `DeleteRange()` after loop or `Delete()` within loop? If it is `DeleteRange()`, then what end iterator must be passed as a parameter?

```
QScopedPointer<Iterator> it(m_db->NewIterator(ReadOptions()));
for (it->SeekToFirst(); it->Valid(); it->Next()) 
{
 // filling POD collection
}
```

Comment: [`DeleteRange`](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/DeleteRange) takes a pair of iterators - the "from" and "to" positions, and deletes everything in between. What is your question exactly?

Comment: What should I use for "to"? `it->SeekToLast()->Next()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DeleteRange(start, end) where start is inclusive and end is exclusive. This is atomic and may be faster than using Delete() within loop.